# Why don't big PCs/laptops open as quick as small phones?

Tags: windows, laptop, speed, desktop-customization, smartphone

If I click a small button on the side of my smart phone, it starts, and I can do what I desire, within almost no time gap. But, to use my laptop, it runs--I am using windows--for a while after clicking the start button. Why do laptops with more better small machines in them, have this long starting process, can't they directly show up the home page immediately after pressing the button?

Edit (16:18 IST): Is it possible to customize my windows to open up home page quickly after pressing the start button? Or should I use any other OS?

Edit (15:44 IST): As I am seeing from the recent [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1175749/why-dont-big-pcs-laptops-open-as-quick-as-small-phones/1175751#1175751) and [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1175749/why-dont-big-pcs-laptops-open-as-quick-as-small-phones#comment1700368_1175749), it seems that phone will be in switched on mode almost often under use. If I choose to keep my laptop in sleep, it does take time to get into work quickly after waking it up than my phone, and considering the machinery of laptops, I don't think they should ever be back of phone even in waking up, even if they get attacked by malware; I don't know whether it is the same case for everyone. And is it optimal to allow PC in hibernate/sleep mode, to allow the quick wake up, won't there be any problem?

Would you all recommend to switch off laptops at a certain frequency like we do in phones? Often I don't switch off my phone at all, I charge it before  going off; can laptops run for a long time having intermediate sleep modes, without getting switched off?

Comment: Mobile devices are always on standby and ready to go. If you left your desktop on, as many do, there would be no lag time at all

Comment: @InterLinked: Thank you for the comment. I have now edited the question description.

Comment: "Would you all recommend to switch off laptops at a certain frequency" - it depends on the OS you have, your use pattern, softwares / updates you install .... Restarting it when you feel it's getting slower I think is just fine

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Thank you for the comment. Can you suggest an OS for the quick performance? I don't use many softwares.

Comment: Your questions are really confusing:(. You're really far from your original question and going to an off-topic direction. Please read help center to learn what's on-topic and how to ask a good question. Also please edit your question with the new information instead of asking them in comments.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I have added the previous comment in the post :) Sorry, I am new here. I will try to narrow the questions.

Answer (score 2):

> If I click a small button on the side of my smart phone, it starts

Your smartphone is already switched on, by pressing the button you just wake it up.

> Why do laptops with more better small machines in them, have this long starting process

You're comparing different things. PCs / laptops with new OS versions also turns on immediately when you wake them up from SLEEP.

Switching on a completely turned-off device takes time for both PCs and phones.

Comment: *"PCs / laptops with new OS versions also turns on immediately when you wake them up from SLEEP."* What I am thinking is, considering the hardware of laptop, even if there is an old OS, shouldn't it turn on immediately after waking it up?,